# How do i plot a XY plot and XZ plot in a 3D plot?

Tags: plot, octave

I'm trying to plot two graph. One XY and one XZ in a 3D graph.
So far i only got this, and my issue is that plot 2 uses my second variable as a y coordinate and i don't know how to make it a Z. I've tried placing a 800 as constant Y, but octave doesn't seem to agree.

```
clear;
[amp, knak, cap]=textread('Octave.csv');

figure(1);
plot3(amp, knak); %%plot 1
hold on;
plot3(amp, cap); %%plot 2
xlabel('amplitude');
ylabel('knakfrekvens');
xlim([0, 25]);
ylim([800, 1500])
zlim([-2E-06, 0]);
zlabel('capacitet');
legend('capacitet', 'knakfrekvens');
grid on;
hold off;
```

Comment: Please include the file Octave.csv so we can reproduce your result.

Answer (score 0):

Making a Z is right direction. However, X and Y are matrix and Z have to be matrix.

Function plot3 takes three cordinates when it tries to plot a line in 3D. If it takes only two cordinates, it will take the cordinates as x and y and plot it on xy plane. You may specify one more cordinate to make **plot3** plot the line on the plane you want.

There is an example:

```
t = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = sin(t);
z = sin(t+(0.5*pi));

figure(1);
#on -z=1 plane
plot3(t, y, -1*ones(1, length(t)), 'linewidth', 5, "-");
hold("on");
#on y=1 plane
plot3(t, ones(1, length(t)), z, 'linewidth', 5, "-"); %%plot 2
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z');
grid("on");
hold("off");
```

[image]